# regular expression for validating multiple fixed strings

Tags: regex

I currently have a regular expression that allows for the string 'red' in lowercase, uppercase and with spaces surrounding it:

```
/red/i
```

How would this regular expression be extended to check for multiple words such as rot, rouge, red and rojo.?

I am using a [Javascript plugin](http://formvalidator.net/#default-validators_custom) which does not support flags. This regex also takes the same form in JavaScript in a none literal format, how would this be extended in the same way?

```
^\s*[Rr][Ee][Dd]\s*$
```

Comment: /red|blue|green/ig https://regex101.com/r/hL7fZ9/1

Comment: Is your question about case sensitivity or multi-language support?

Comment: It is about case sensitivity, checking a string that can appear in 4 different ways - then extending a validation regex in a literal and none literal format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the OR operator in your regex:

```
/(blue|green|red)/i
```

Comment: Thank you very much - as an extension to my question - I have the same regex in JavaScript ^\s*[Rr][Ee][Dd]\s*$ is there any way to extend this is the same way?

Comment: Why don't you just use `/^\s(red)\s*$/i` ?

Comment: The string the user enters varies on the language selected. This is the word red. I am using a JavaScript plugin which doesn't support flags. The different versions of this string are rot, rouge, red and rojo.

Comment: Post the full code relevant to your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many dialect's of regular expressions. However, in this case the following would work in most cases:

```
/red|green|yellow|blue/i
```